# Automating/scripting Wifi connections

Tags: wifi, ubuntu-14.04

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 with an external wifi key.

My goal is to successfully connect to a wifi spot without going through the GUI using a script 
I have tried the following commands:

```
-nmcli nm wifi on 
-nmcli -p dev wifi 
-nmcli con up id "essid"
```

The second command gives me a good list of available wifi issues, however when I try to connect with the third command an error prevents the connection:

```
-Error: Unknown login: my "essid".
```

I've tried many other commands located in the wireless part of the forum, but without success. 
If I use the GUI and just click once on a wifi spot to connect it without the above commands It Works.

Thank you for your interest in my concern.
Sorry for my very bad english.

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/92799/connecting-to-wifi-network-through-command-line

Answer (score 0):

"nmcli con up" only connects to existing connections and uses the saved named of the connetion as ID, not the SSID of the network.

To connect to a "new" wireless network use:
nmcli wifi connect <(B)SSID> [password ] [wep-key-type key|phrase]

Answer (score 0):

If you can live without NM, then what I used to do in order to programatically connect to wifi networks was to use iwconfig and dhclient.

In order to associate to the wireless AP:

`iwconfig YOUR_INTERFACE essid YOUR_ESSID channel YOUR_WIFI_CHANNEL key YOUR_PSK`

In order to get an IP address via DHCP:

`dhclient YOUR_INTERFACE`

Note that if NM is still running, this will not work.